# Getting 404 not found when running npx run-android - react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react-native application, everything runs smoothly on iOS, when running the following command:

> npx run-android

I get the following error:

> npm ERR! code E404 npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/run-android - Not found npm ERR! 404  npm
> ERR! 404  'run-android@latest' is not in this registry. npm ERR! 404
> npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a npm ERR! 404
> tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

When I navigate to https://registry.npmjs.org/run-android it shows as not found, what do I do in this situation? I'm unable to find anything online to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Command to install and launch your app on the device.

```
npx react-native run-android
```